# User cannot place order twice

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, backend, e-commerce

I'm facing a weird issue while placing order in my ecommerce. when i place order the 1st time it registers and saves the order in my database but when the same user tries to place order the 2nd time i get a weird error.

my api call -

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const makeRequest = async ()=>{
        try{
            const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/pay", {
                tokenId:stripeToken.id,
                amount: cart.total,
            })
            try {
                userRequest.post('/orders', {
                    userId: userr._id,
                    products: cart.products.map((item) => ({
                        productName: item.title,
                        productId: item._id,
                        quantity: item._quantity,
                    })),
                    amount: cart.total,
                    address: res.data.billing_details.address,
                })
                history('/success'); 
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    };
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
}, [stripeToken, cart.total, history])
```

order model -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userId: {type: String, required: true},
        products: [
            {
                productName: {type: String},
                productId: {type: String},
                quantity: {type: Number, default: 1},
                
            },
        ],
        amount: {type:Number, required:true},
        address: { type: Object, required:true },
        status: {type: String, default: 'pending'},
    }, {timestamps: true}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

order route -

```
router.post("/", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
      const newOrder = new Order(req.body);
    
      try {
        const savedOrder = await newOrder.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedOrder);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    });
```

error message when placing order 2nd time__
[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening because `backend` creates the same `document` again when the same `user` places the same `order` a second time.

So what you can do is create a function in the backend which checks if  `the user` has already ordered the same `product` then you can just `increase` the `quantity of the product` in the document for the same `user`.

Comment: But i wanted to keep the orders separate cause customers can place orders at different times. It should be able to take multiple orders from the same customer.

Comment: I'm talking about `increasing the quantity` only before `customer checks out the order` after `customer checks out the order` then `customer` can `order` the same `product` again you can create a new `document` for it.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the problem is that you try to add the same _id twice, in the second time that you want to insert to cart you need to **update** the order and not make a new one(newOrder.save();)
so before you save new order first check if there is a new order if not make newOrder.save() else you need to )update the cart
if you using mongoose(**findOneAndUpdate**)

Comment: what if the customer decides to order twice separately?

Comment: so make a new id for each order, but why do you want that?

Comment: how do i make a new id for each order?